# How to get all user interaction events from a specific UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer, swift2

I'm trying to find a way to get user events from a `UIViewController` so that I can set a timeout timer and reset it when the user touches the screen.

If the user doesn't touch the screen after a certain amount of time, I'm going to dismiss the `UIViewController`. I have all the timer code, etc. The problem is when I attach a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the view of the view controller, the events aren't being handled and the normal operation of the view doesn't work. Is there a way in which I can just use the events to detect when to reset the timer without having to handle any of the events?

Also want to note that I don't have control over the `UIViewController` since it's a part of a library. I'm merely presenting it with `presentViewController()`

Comment: Are you sure that you're attaching gesture recognizer after view was created (it's not `nil` at that point)?